# Finding the analytic function whose real part is given

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, complex-numbers

This is an easy question; I probably make some computation mistake. I need to find the analytic function of which u is the real part

I have $u(x,y)=2x^2+2x-2y^2+1$

To find the analytic function of which $u$ is a real part, I need to write,

$\frac {du}{dx}=\frac{dv}{dy}\implies \frac{dv}{dy}=4x+2\implies v(x,y)=4xy+2y;$

Now, we also need $\frac {du}{dy}=-\frac{dv}{dx}\implies -\frac {dv}{dx}=-4y\implies v(x,y)=4xy$

Now I do not know what the function $f$ is. Can someone please give a hint? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Here's a question: does your $v(x,y)=4xy+2y$ satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations?

Comment: what do you mean @charlestoncrabb ?

Comment: When $\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}=4x+2$, then in general $v=4xy+2y+f(x)$, where $f(x)$ is an integration "constant" with respect to $y$.  Now, can you proceed?

Comment: @Peter I have shown the calculations, I get different things, not $-4y$ every time

Comment: @Dr.MV can you elaborate a little more?

Comment: You actually have the correct answer.  The function $f$ will be a constant and irrelevant.

Comment: I am confused. is then $v(x,y)=4xy+2y$?

Comment: Yes. $v=4xy+2y$.

Comment: When you wrote $\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}=-4y$ then one can only deduce that $v=-4yx+\text{some function of only y}$.  But we already had that "some function;" it was $2y$.

Answer (score 4):

Since $\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}= 4x+ 2$, $v(x,y)= 4xy+ 2y+ \phi(x)$ where $\phi(x)$ is an arbitrary function of x (since partial differentiation with respect to y treats x as a constant, the derivative of any function of x only, with respect to y, is 0).  From that $\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}=  4y+ \phi'(x)= 4y$ so $\phi'(x)= 0$ and $\phi(x)$ is a constant.  That is, $v= 4xy+ 2y+ C$ where C can be any constant.  Since f(x, y)= u(x,y)+ iv(x,y), $f(x,y)= 2x^2+ 2x- 2y^2+ 1+ (4xy+ 2y+ C)i$.

Comment: If we are sure that u(x, y)  is the real part of an analytic function f(z), then f(z) =u(z, 0)+iC for some real constant C.

Answer (score 0):

There is a short cut method: Replace x by z=x+iy   and y by 0  in u(x, y) and add a purely imaginary constant.The resulting function is the analytic function for which u(x, y)  is the real part. Thus f(z) =u(z, 0)++iC